# That means the panel is 6 bit and can simulate 8 bit with FRC?

Tags: display, rgb, color-depth

How could I know if the monitor panel is true 8 bit or 6 bit+FRC?

I ask because even though the panel is rated to be 8 bit, from graphic driver I can select 8 bit and also 6 bit color depth. This seems to me to be a hint that the panel is 6 bit. I might be wrong in this assumption.

That means the panel is 6 bit and can simulate 8 bit with FRC?
If not, then all monitors can display ( can be selected from graphic driver ) a lowered 6 bit even if the panel is true 8 bit color depth?

The Pixel Format is Full RGB 4:4:4. Connection is DP 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

The driver setup should show the maximum values, and lower. For instance, you can choose any resolution including native and any lower res, but nothing higher shows. So, the panel EDID (digital ID info) is telling the OS that both 6-bpp and 8-bpp will work with that panel.